# Getting gps data from blackberry (pearl) directly from usb interface

Tags: blackberry, java-me, usb, gps, rim-4.5

Has anyone researched how to access the gps chipset on a blackberry over usb so that it is  unnecessary to transmit this data over the cell carrier's data network?

Is it possible to access the GPS chipset, store information in a buffer, and open an interface connection (over the usb charging port), for access?  Not sure if J2ME allows for this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checkout the "UsbDemo" project and the "GPSDemo" that are included in the blackberry JDE.

the GPSDemo listens to the GPS and stores the location information into a buffer that gets sent over the network.

The USB Demo shows how to interact with a desktop client over USB.

You should be able to pull on the network code from the GPS Demo and put in the the code to talk over USB.